# Function mapping definition and calculating with logic symbols

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

Im wondering if the notation of the following function is correct?

$f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$

$n \mapsto 7+5n$

$f(n) = n-1$

That the inputs and outputs to this function are

```
n=0 => f(7)  = 6
n=1 => f(12) = 11
n=2 => f(17) = 16
n=3 => f(22) = 21
```

? or does it work like this?

```
n=0 => f(0) = 6
n=1 => f(1) = 11
n=2 => f(2) = 16
n=3 => f(3) = 21
```

Is subtraction allowed in $\mathbb N$ ? or should I define it in $\mathbb Z^+$?

Another question I have is, is it possible in mathematics to use boolean algebra symbols when working with functions where $n \in \mathbb N$, for example $f(n) = 5n + (n+1) \oplus (n-1)$ and compute with algebraic symbols?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather you are defining $\mathbb{N}$ to be the set of nonnegative integers $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

We cannot define a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n) = n - 1$ since $f(0) = -1 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

That problem can be fixed by defining $f$ to be the function $f: \mathbb{Z}^{+} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n) = n - 1$.

With that definition, we obtain
\begin{align*}
f(1) & = 0\\
f(2) & = 1\\
f(3) & = 2
\end{align*}

If we define a new function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ by $g(n) = 5n + 7$, then we can define the *composition* of $f$ and $g$, $f \circ g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by 
$$(f \circ g)(n) = f(g(n)) = f(5n + 7) = 5n + 6$$

We then obtain
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(0) & = 6\\
(f \circ g)(1) & = 11\\
(f \circ g)(2) & = 16\\
(f \circ g)(3) & = 21
\end{align*}
For the composition $f \circ g$ to be defined, we require that the range of $g$ be a subset of the domain of $f$ and that the range of $f \circ g$ be contained in $\mathbb{N}$. Since $g$ maps $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}^+$, the range of $g$ is in the domain of $f$.  Since $(g \circ f)(n) = 5n + 6$ is an increasing function that assumes integer values when the input is an integer and $(g \circ f)(0) = 6$, $(g \circ f)(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If we define the composition of $g$ and $f$, $g \circ f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{N}$ by 
$$(g \circ f)(n) = g(f(n)) = g(n - 1) = 5(n - 1) + 7 = 5n - 5 + 7 = 5n + 2$$
Since $f$ maps $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{N}$, the range of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$.  Since $(g \circ f)(n) = 5n - 2$ is an increasing function that assumes integer values when the input is an integer and $(g \circ f)(1) = 7$, $g \circ f \in \mathbb{N}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.  Hence, the composition is well-defined.  With this definition, we obtain
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(1) & = 7\\
(f \circ g)(2) & = 12\\
(f \circ g)(3) & = 17
\end{align*}

In Boolean algebra, the variables are truth values.  You could define the symbols of Boolean algebra to have another meaning when applied to the integers, although that could be a source of confusion.

Comment: I understood everything until the composition definition. Thank for the comprehensive explanation, though how did you get $5n+2$ at the latter half? Isn't your composition definition supposed to be:
$(g\circ f)(n)=g(f(n))=g(n-1)=5(n-1)+6=5n-5+6=5n+1$
instead of $+7$ ?

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy  No. Since $g(n) = 5n + 7$, $g(f(n))$ is the result of adding $7$ to $5$ times $f(n)$.  Hence, $(g \circ f)(n) = g(f(n)) = 5(f(n)) + 7 = 5(n - 1) + 7 = 5n - 5 + 7 = 5n + 2$.

Comment: After some fiddling I found out if this also would work, if swapping the functions? $(f \circ g)(n)=f(g(n))=g(n)-1=7+5n-1=6+5n.$ Would this also be a definition?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  You can compare your answer with the one I gave in my answer for $(f \circ g)(n)$.